# Find all occurrences of one 2D array inside another 2D array

Tags: javascript, image-processing

In JavaScript, I'm trying to find all matching coordinates of this 2D integer array:

[image]

inside this 2D integer array, with overlapping sub-arrays being counted:

[image]

Each image represents a 2D JavaScript integer array, and the black pixels correspond to `1`, and the yellow pixels correspond to `0`, but I depicted the arrays this way so that they would be easier to visualize.

So how can I find all matches of the array [image] inside the array [image]?

Here's the function I'm trying to implement:

```
findAllMatchesOfOne2DArrayInsideAnother2DArray(containedArray, containingArray){
    //find all matching coordinates of containedArray inside containingArray, and return a 2D array of coordinates
}
```

Comment: This is not a 'find array inside array' problem, this is an image processing problem. I suggest you edit/retag your question to indicate this. It would also be good to say for what purpose you need this, in case there's a simpler solution.

Comment: @Patashu I'm trying to find all occurrences of one image inside another image, but each pixel in each image is represented by a single integer. So I'm trying to find all matches of one integer 2D integer array inside another 2D image array.

Comment: there are not sub-arrays in a 2d array, nor can sub-arrays overlap like you show. you are not looking for a sub-array at all, you are looking for 5 points that, other than the middle 3 in a row, are several elements away from each other: width +/- 1 and height +/- 1...

Comment: @dandavis Why is it incorrect to refer to rectangular regions within a 2D array as "sub-arrays"?

Comment: Before trying to answer, is this a representation of a tilemap? Can i say that a single cross is something similar to [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0]? If it is a tilemap, how can you have overlapping tiles?

Comment: each "sub" as you call it is actually three different arrays, and they don't appear next to each other. in short, you need to jump over the pixels in the flat array to match the top, middle, and bottom 2d arrays to the master flat arrays, where each one of the three will appear at some point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a way](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq3u2/) to get all occurances of any given 2D array inside another 2D array. It is assumed that all subarrays have the same dimension (nothing like `[[1,0,0],[1,0]]`).

```
var x = [[0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,1,1,0,0,1,0],
        [0,1,0,0,1,1,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0,0,0]];

var y = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]];

var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length - y.length + 1; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < x[0].length - y[0].length + 1; k++) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var l = 0; l < y.length; l++) {
             for (var m = 0; m < y[l].length; m++) {
                count += Math.abs(y[l][m] - x[i + l][k + m]);
            }       
        }
        if (count === 0) {
            res.push([i, k]);
        }

    }
}
```

The array `res` will contain the "coordinates" of the top-left corner of each match. I'm sure you'll find better performing algorithms but this one seems to work :)

Comment: @Anderson Green: Thanks for adding the fiddle!